# How to compare dataGrid date value to current date?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a column called `Review Date` from MySQL. Formatted as `dd/mm/yyyy`.

I simply show it on the dataGridView.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sDJK.jpg)

I am trying to create a statement to compare today's date to the dataGrid values.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    private void data_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        string todayDate = today.ToString("d/M/yyyy");


        foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in data.Rows)
        {
            // Cell 6 is the review_date
            if (Myrow.Cells[6].Value.ToString() < todayDate)
            {
                Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I get an error:

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: If the dates are stored as strings and not dates in the database that should be changed, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Date` objects.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in data.Rows)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(Myrow.Cells[6].Value.ToString());

    if (dt > today)
    {
        Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Also, quick tip.

If you'd like to add days or months to your date. Try this...

```
//Add days
if (dt > today.AddDays(10))

//Add months
if (dt > today.AddMonths(12))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a less than operator on strings like that. You need to do the comparison the date objects. Something like this perhaps.

```
private void data_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today.Date; //Used .Date to cut off time too

    foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in data.Rows)
    {
        var GridDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
        DateTime.TryParse(Myrow.Cells[6], out GridDate); //parse string date

        //Cell 6 is the review_date
        if (GridDate < todayDate)
        {
            Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```